# Non linear Constrained Optimisation in R

Tags: r, optimization, sum

I am trying to project survival rates for a specific disease. The only information I have is survival rates at 1 year, 3 years, 5 years and 10 years after diagnosis.

For example:

S, which is the survival rate

```
S<-c(81,78,72,65)
```

x, the time after diagnosis

```
x<-c(1,3,5,10)
```

I am trying to test a few functions that would allow me to estimate the survival rate after 20 years.

One of my functions was defined as

f(x)= exp(ax^b), a and b were unknown but needed to be positive. I have used the code very kindly provided by fmarm but have tested with another function.

f(x) = (1 + (x/a)^b)^-1

However, I am getting very weird values, all below 1 and I can't seem to figure why. Have I missed something?

```
S<-c(81,78,72,65)
x<-c(1,3,5,10)

f<-function(ab)
{
  a <- ab[1]
  b <- ab[2]
  return(sum((((1+(x/a)**b)**-1)-S)**2))
}

minim <- nlm(f,p=c(1,1))

ab <- minim$estimate

a_opt <- ab[1]
b_opt <- ab[2]

prediction_exp <- function(x){
  return((1+(x/a_opt)**b_opt)**-1)
}
prediction_exp(20)

plot(prediction_exp(1:20), type="l", col="blue", xlab="Nb d'années après diagnostic", ylab="survie nette en %")
lines(x,S,col="black")
```

P.S : I have found my mistake. The S vector needed to be under 1 and the function was supposed to be x*a and not (x/a). Thanks again fmarm to helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, S and x are fixed and you want to find a and b that minimize sum(i=1 to 4) exp(a*x[i]**b)-S[i])**2

You can create a function

```
f <- function(ab){
  a <- ab[1]
  b <- ab[2]
  return(sum((exp(a*x**b)-S)**2))
}
```

ab is a vector of length 2 containing a in first place and b in second

To minimize this function you can use `nlm`

```
minim <- nlm(f,p=c(0,0))
```

You have to give p : starting parameters for ab. As I had no idea what could be good I just put a=0 and b=0
The result has an estimate component that gives you the best parameters found by the algorithm

```
ab <- minim$estimate
```

Then you can extract a and b from ab

```
a_opt <- ab[1]
b_opt <- ab[2]
```

You can create your prediction function

```
prediction_exp <- function(x){
  return(exp(a_opt*x**b_opt))
}
prediction_exp(20)
```

The  survival rate predicted after 20 years is approximately 63%

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The SO setup recommends thatt you not use comments for giving thanks instead they provide the checkmark system which you have used appropriately. Personally I would have expected survivals to be in teh range of [0-1]

Answer (score 1):

This is just the code offered in the accepted answer with proper survival results (constrained to the interval [0-1], and corrected results:

```
S<-c(81,78,72,65)/100
x<-c(1,3,5,10)

f<-function(ab)
{
    a <- ab[1]
    b <- ab[2]
    return(sum((((1+(x*a)**b)**-1)-S)**2))
}

minim <- nlm(f,p=c(1,1))

ab <- minim$estimate

a_opt <- ab[1]
b_opt <- ab[2]

prediction_exp <- function(x){
    return((1+(x*a_opt)**b_opt)**-1)
}
prediction_exp(20)
[1] 0.5975635

png(); plot(prediction_exp(1:20), type="l", col="blue", xlab="Nb d'années après diagnostic", ylab="survie nette en %")
lines(x,S,col="black") ; dev.off()
```

[image]